# Values added in the GridView are not saved in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Here is my following code:

```
string csr = "connection string";
string add = "Insert INTO table (Column1,Column2,Column3) Values (@Column1,@Column2,@Column3)";
using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(csr))
{
    using ( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(add,connect))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column1",textbox1.text");
        //and so on
        connect.Open();
        command.ExecuteReader();
        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

I can see the data added in the gridview but when I check the table data in c# is empty, no value added. what's wrong?

Comment: ok , and still not showing in the database.

Comment: noh it works now , I closed the database tab, maybe it was because of close.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `connect.Close();`, the `using` statement will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column1",textbox1.text")
```

should be

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column1",textbox1.text)
```

Set a breakpoint and ensure your connectionstring was properly set, textbox has a value, etc...